# Bootstrap toggle button not showing all nav-right items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I played around with the navbar and have  situated it below the header pic. Everything looks ok on full screen. But on mobiles the navbar-right items are hidden in the toggle.  Can anyone tell me why?

Bootply:  http://www.bootply.com/zmpMWqSmyU

html:

```
  <!-- header pic --> 
     <div class ="row">
      <img src ="1.jpg" class ="img-responsive">   
        </div>
          </div>



    <!-- Navigation -->

         <div class = "navbar navbar-transaparent navbar-fixed-top" role  
           ="navigation"> 
           <div class ="container">
               <div class = "navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  
          data-toggle="collapse"    data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div> <!-- end of navbar header -->

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">About us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>

      </ul>

  </div>

    <a class = "navbar-brand" href="#"> <h1 style="font 
        size:80px;">Lily       </h1></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
        </div> <!-- end of container -->
           </div> <!-- end of navbar -->


  css 

  .nav {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 520px;
  }


   .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;


   }

    .navbar-brand {   
      color: #ff5bae;
       text-align: center;
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 6.0%;
        left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }

    }

    .navbar-brand:hover{
  color:#bcaacf;
   }


  #myNavbar li>a:hover{
    color: #ffe6d7;
    background-color: #bcaacf;
    }

   .nav.navbar-nav li>a {
    color: black;
     }
```

Comment: Hey @gitly, welcome to stack overflow. Can you possibly add the relevant code directly to the question? This makes it more likely for you to get decent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is both your `myNavbar`s have the same id.

You can't give multiple elements the same id; the javascript that does the collapsing/un-collapsing will only ever get one of them. So, when you click your button:

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target="#myNavbar">`

It will only show one of the two:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="myNavbar">`

You can fix this by using classes instead. Multiple items can have the same class. First, change your `data-target` in your button to `.myNavbar`. Like so:

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target=".myNavbar">`

Then, change both of your navbars. Remove the id and add it to the class list. Like so:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left myNavbar">`

Additionally, you have malformed html in one of your `myNavbar`s:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">About us </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Should be:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">About us </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @gitly Glad to hear it! Don't forget to accept the answer so people who look at this question in the future know it fixed the issue.